# Xamarin android Pass time between activity and reset from other activity

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to `xamarin` android.
I have an issue for reseting time 
I want to pass time to `SeeTime` activity and reset time to 60 from that activity which will also reset time in the `MainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
       public EditText timer;
        Button btn;
        public int elapsedTime;    // counting values integer
        Handler myHandler;   // used to delay runnable for a second which delay_RATE
        int delay_RATE = 1000;    //delay
        Java.Lang.Runnable r;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            elapsedTime = 60; // default value
            myHandler = new Handler();     //initializing handler
            r = new Java.Lang.Runnable(Run);
            timer = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.timertxt);
            btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1);
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            Counter();
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            elapsedTime = 20;
            StartActivity(typeof(SeeTime));
        }

        void Counter()
        {
            elapsedTime--;      // increment
            timer.Text = elapsedTime.ToString();
            myHandler.PostDelayed(r, delay_RATE);
            if (elapsedTime == 0)
            {
                elapsedTime = 20;
            }
        }
        void Run()
        { Counter(); }
```

**SeeTime Activity:**

```
public class SeeTime : Activity
    {
        MainActivity mainActivity;
        private EditText timer;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Time);
            timer = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtTime);
            mainActivity = new MainActivity();

            timer.Text = mainActivity.timer.Text;
            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I posted an answer and hope it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following method to pass `elapsedTime` from `MainActivity` to `SeeTime` activity.

//MainActivity

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SeeTime));
intent.PutExtra("Timer", elapsedTime);
StartActivity(intent);
```

//SeeTime acticity

```
int intValue = Intent.Extras.GetInt("Timer", 20);
```

Besides, when you return from `SeeTime` activity to `MainActivity`, you can use `OnResume()` method to reset `elapsedTime` to 60. For details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/

So the code is like this:

MainActivity

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;

namespace App80
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public EditText timer;
        Button btn;
        public int elapsedTime;    // counting values integer
        Handler myHandler;   // used to delay runnable for a second which delay_RATE
        int delay_RATE = 1000;    //delay
        Java.Lang.Runnable r;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            elapsedTime = 60; // default value
            myHandler = new Handler();     //initializing handler
            r = new Java.Lang.Runnable(Run);
            timer = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.timertxt);
            btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1);
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            Counter();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            elapsedTime = 60;
            timer.Text = elapsedTime.ToString();
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SeeTime));
            intent.PutExtra("Timer", elapsedTime);
            StartActivity(intent);

        }

        void Counter()
        {
            elapsedTime--;      // increment
            timer.Text = elapsedTime.ToString();
            myHandler.PostDelayed(r, delay_RATE);
            if (elapsedTime == 0)
            {
                elapsedTime = 20;
            }
        }
        void Run()
        { Counter(); }
    }
}
```

SeeTime Activity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App80
{
    [Activity(Label = "SeeTime")]
    public class SeeTime : Activity
    {
        //MainActivity mainActivity;
        private EditText timer;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Time);
            timer = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtTime);

            int intValue = Intent.Extras.GetInt("Timer", 20);

            timer.Text = intValue.ToString();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i got answer

Comment: @Hafeezali  If my answer could help, I would be appreciated if you can mark it.